# Speeker Identification (Machine Learning)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to implement Hidden Markov Model based speech recognition system. Since, speech recognition is a vast field, I want to implement speeker identification first.

**I wanted to know, if speeker identification is simpler compared to Speech Recognition**. So that I can implement speeker identification first and once I get grip of it, I can proceed for full implemenation of speech recognition.

I do not want to use any build in libraries of MATLAB/Python. I would like to write my own. However, to begin with I can use some libraries and understand the working concept of it. Please suggest if you have good resources in speeker identification.

Thanks, 
Aravind

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of resources available, books, journals, sources, programs. But let me  suggest very simple algorithm. 
1. Train/Save HMM acoustic model for each speaker. If u have 10 speakers, than u have ten models.

2. Now ask a current speaker  to say  magic words like 'Ok google'. Now recognize it against every  models saved. So u have  scores for every model. of course the right speaker is the model with highest score.

Which with [HTK](https://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/)  only bash/shell programming is required. No c/python or matlab involved

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check.